# Staying in Turkey illegally as a Russian - what are the consequences?

Tags: visa, residency, overstay, turkey, russian-citizens

My parents are Russian.
They are allowed to stay in Turkey legally without a visa for a max of 90 days for every 180 days. They've applied for a 1 year touristic residence permit (ikamet). It was declined for the 1st parent with an official reason *"one or more conditions sought in Article 32 are not met or no longer apply"* and has a never-changing *"missing documents"* status for a 2nd parent even though all documents were added.

Couple of notes:

- while submitting documents, 2 different immigration officers in 2 different offices claimed that their applications were flawless and permits will be granted.
- after getting the negative permit status immigration officer said *"touristic residency permits are no longer given to russians; it was still possible 2 weeks ago"*. We are talking 1st week of March. Parents quit jobs and left Russia right after the war with Ukraine started, because they stronghly disagree with it and are afraid for what it may mean to them, like mobilisation of medical staff.
- both are retired in their 60s.

What are the repercussions for them if they stay in Turkey illegally for up to a 1 year? When ready to leave, they are prepared to officially confess and pay all the fees before attempting to cross the border. Any other advice is also appreciated.

Comment: The typical repercussions include a fine and a re-entry ban, and possible removal. https://ikamet.com/blog/consequences-of-overstaying-on-a-turkish-visa

Comment: And note that this might not be treated the same as a usual overstay.  They are in a sense undeclared refugees.

Comment: And note that having attracted attention through a residency application that has been refused, staying on in Turkey may  be problematic if Immigration authorities decide to follow up on the refusal

Comment: @Traveller, Loren Pechtel, 
thanks guys! That answers it.